# DialogFragment dissapearing when opening keyboard for EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` that uses a layout which has `ConstraintLayout` inside `ConstraintLayout` and when I click on `EditText`, the keyboard opens up and `dialog` dissapears.

My xml structure:

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <ConstraintLayout>
        <EditText>
    </ConstraintLayout>

    <ConstraintLayout>
        <EditText>
    </ConstraintLayout>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

I also tried out structure like this:

```
<ConstraintLayout>
        <EditText>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

And with the last structure the dialog does not dissapear.

In my code I need to have `ConstraintLayout` inside `ConstraintLayout` because I need to show one of them at some time and the other one at some other time in my dialog.

I have tried to fix it but I have no ideas left.

**EDIT**

I also found another reason for it happening.

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/..."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/..." />
    </ConstraintLayout>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

When it's `wrap_content` then the `dialog` is not dissapearing but then the view's are not covering the whole screen.

If i change it to `match_parent` the dialog will look as intended but then it will start dissapearing.. So it has something to do with the `match_parent` dialog when keyboard shows up.

Code to show the dialog in `Activity`:

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    NewPointDialog newPointDialog = NewPointDialog.newInstace();
    String finalUserId = userId;
    newPointDialog.setNewPointClickListener(new NewPointDialog.OnNewPointClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancelClicked() {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onAcceptClicked() {
            ...
        }
    });
    newPointDialog.show(fm, "new_point_frag");
```

and `NewPointDialog`:

```
public class NewPointDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public interface OnNewPointClickListener {
        void onCancelClicked();
        void onAcceptClicked();
    }

    private OnNewPointClickListener listener;

    public NewPointDialog(){
    }

    public static NewPointDialog newInstace(){
        NewPointDialog fragment = new NewPointDialog();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_new_sequence_1, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        cancleDialog.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            listener.onCancelClicked();
            dismiss();
        });

        saveDialog.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            ...
            listener.onAcceptClicked();
        });
    }

    public void setNewPointClickListener(OnNewPointClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it.. didnt work

Comment: Post the code where you show the dialog

Comment: If you need to show Edit text at different times, you can use visibility parameter right?

Comment: Kindly share the edittext xml code in your layout

Comment: Sorry for taking so long but I added the code to show the dialog and edittext xml.

Comment: There was a comment before to use `LinearLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout` and at first it didnt work but after trying it a bit, I got `LinearLayout` to work. I would like it more if I could still use the `ConstraintLayout` and find the issue here but I can also switch to `Linear`.

Comment: In your activity tag for your manifest have your tried adding `android: windowSoftInputMode ="adjustNothing"`

Comment: But yeah I cant replicate anything with the code given, maybe creating a better  http://sscce.org/ would help get you a better response.